# How to stop IntelliJ from automatically importing org.jetbrains.annotations in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

My superclass has a method signature with parameters that use `javax` annotations like so:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public abstract class Nanana {

    // ...

    protected abstract void nanaFunction(
        @Nonnull final Parameter parParameter1,
        @Nullable final Parameter parParameter2
    ) { /* ... */ }
}
```

And when I inherit from this class in a different file without manually importing the annotations, it autocompletes my override like so (notice the annotation imports):

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

public class ConcreteNanana extends Nanana {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void nanaFunction(
        @NotNull final Parameter parParameter1,
        @Nullable final Parameter parParameter2
    ) { /* ... */ }
}
```

How do I configure IntelliJ to import the same annotations as the superclass? I am using IntelliJ 2020.3.3 Ultimate.

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  The IDE lets me import the annotations I like in the subclass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253324)

This is a defect and you can solve it by:

`Settings --> Inspections --> Java --> Probable bugs --> Nullability problems --> @NotNull/@Nullable problems --> Configure Annotations`

And Set the defaults

```
javax.annotation.Nullable
javax.annotation.Nonnull
```

Restart and should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

@Nonnull/@Nullable annotations configuration in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1:

```
Menu 
> File
  > Preferences
    > Editor
      > Inspections

Inspections
> Java
  > Probable bugs
    > Nullability problems
      > @NonNull/@Nullable problems

@NonNull/@Nullable problems
> Options
  > Configure annotations
    > Select preferred `Nullable` annotation
    > Press micro-accept button (see screenshot, horrible UX)
    > Select preferred `Nonnull` annotation
    > Press micro-accept button
  > Ok
>Ok

No restart needed
```

[image]